# Using wordpress and django togther

Tags: php, python, django, wordpress

I am developing a web application using Django and python. We have also a public website where a customer can find information regarding our products. I was thinking to implement this website using WordPress or other well known php CMS, since the content may be modified by people who don't know how to code.

A user must login to access our web application. The login should be located in the public website (built using php and a CMS) along with the registration form. The user model is already implemented in the web application and therefore is not available in the CMS/php. I was thinking to include a login page written in python by means of an iframe. is it a good idea?

Is there a neat solution for this problem? Is a good idea to mix up php/cms and python/Django?

Comment: You should look into WordPress' XML-RPC

Comment: Why....are you mixing these? Django **IS** a CMS for Python. This sounds extremely convoluted and likely it's a huge waste of your time.

Comment: just redo the webapp as a wordpress admin page. and if you are too lazy for that then iframe it on the wordpress admin page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an opensource `CMS` for Django called [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/). Its very elegant.

> In some ways, Mezzanine resembles tools such as Wordpress that provide an intuitive interface for managing pages, blog posts, form data, store products, and other types of content. But Mezzanine is also different. Unlike many other platforms that make extensive use of modules or reusable applications, Mezzanine provides most of its functionality by default. This approach yields a more integrated and efficient platform

Follow this link to [download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Mezzanine) and have a look at its features

Regarding you question `Is a good idea to mix up php/cms and python/Django?`, No, because Django is `Python` based and wordrepss is `PHP` based. Although you can sync data by writing different scripts that require some knowledge of both ends.

Comment: Should the db of the cms the same as my web app?

Answer (score 1):

There is another option https://www.django-cms.org/
This is specially usefull if you have already a django project, because you can add to the project the CMS components, Mezzanine is a very good option too, but you have to start the project from scratch.